# change confidential stylesheet

Tags: customization, stylesheet

I like the built-in ConfidentialReport Stylesheet under Reports but I would like to be able to change the word "CONFIDENTIAL" displayed at top border to something of my choosing.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: The location where "CONFIDENTIAL" is defined is in a confidential location in the installation folder and can not be disclosed.

Comment: Nasser - I assume you are being serious in a funny way.  Either way, do you know if there is a way to replicate this header-like strip for my own custom report.  Thanks.

Comment: I am just being funny. I could not find where this string is defined. May be a global search could find it. I do not know. It is not in the style sheet either.

Comment: ok...thanks for checking..and it was funny.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run this:

```
Cases[
 Import[
  FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath[
    ToFileName@CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions],
    "StyleSheetPath"
    ] // FrontEndExecute
  ],
 Cell[___, DockedCells -> _, ___],
 \[Infinity]
 ]
```

You'll find it's defined in the `All` style.

I'd suggest either just using:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 DockedCells -> {Cell["S   O   M   E   T   H   I   N   G   -   E   L   S   E", 
   "SBO", CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, 
   CellFrame -> {{0, 0}, {0, 3}}, FontSize -> 12, 
   FontSlant -> "Plain", FontColor -> GrayLevel[1], 
   TextAlignment -> Center, CellFrameColor -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], 
   Background -> RGBColor[0.65, 0.5, 0.45]]}
]
```

Or copying the file to the `$UserBaseDirectory` and editing that:

```
file =
  FrontEndExecute@
   FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath[
    ToFileName@CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions],
    "StyleSheetPath"
    ];
new =
  FileNameJoin@{$UserBaseDirectory, 
    FileNameDrop[file, FileNameDepth[$InstallationDirectory]]};
Quiet@CreateDirectory[DirectoryName[new], 
   CreateIntermediateDirectories -> True];
CopyFile[file, new];
NotebookOpen[new, Editable -> True, Saveable -> True]
```